# Highcharts - Make text inside pie chart responsive

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have created the following Pie Chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/niftyhawk/6Ljnkmwe/

I would like to center the number "100" in the pie chart and make it responsive when window is resized. Currently, the text is centered, but it's not responsive.

```
function(chart) { // on complete
        var textX = chart.plotLeft + (chart.series[0].center[0]);
        var textY = chart.plotTop  + (chart.series[0].center[1]);

        var span = '<span id="pieChartInfoText" style="position:absolute; text-align:center;">';
        span += '<span style="font-size: 32px">Upper</span><br>';
        span += '<span style="font-size: 16px">Lower</span>';
        span += '</span>';

        $("#container").append(span);
        span = $('#pieChartInfoText');
        span.css('left', textX + (span.width() * -0.5));
        span.css('top', textY + (span.height() * -0.5));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the number "100" into subtitle and center it. 
Instead of using the function that @Jake developed, that adds number "100" into the chart after the chart is rendered, it is better to render this number by means of Highcharts.js. One of the possible ways to do it is to use `subtitle` field inside Highcharts.Chart. As in the example below, you should set to it  `align: 'center', verticalAlign: 'middle'`. This will center your number and will be responsive.

The should be a solution to your problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/6Ljnkmwe/5/

```
$(function() {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            innerSize: '40%'
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser Series Chart'
    },
    subtitle: {
            text: '150',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
                            style: { "fontSize": "22px" },
                            y: 15
            },
    credits: { enabled: false},
    series: [{
        data: [
            ['Firefox', 2262],
            ['IE7', 3800],
            ['IE6', 1000],
            ['Chrome', 1986]
            ]}]
});
});
```

Comment: can you add some explanations ?

Comment: Sure. Instead of using the function that @Jake developed, that adds number "100" into the chart after the chart is rendered, it is better to render this number by means of Highcharts.js. One of the possible ways to do it is to use `subtitle` field inside Highcharts.Chart. As in the example above, you should set to it  `align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'middle' `. This will center your number and will be responsive.

Comment: maybe you can put this explanation in your answer

Comment: its not responsive. When screensize is adjusted then this text goes out of the circle